# Cite article number in proceedings, instead of pages

Tags: bibliographies

For some reason some conference sometimes use [page numbers in their proceedings](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2683593&preflayout=flat#prox), and on other years ["article numbers" are used](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2063384&preflayout=flat#prox).

So when I cite one of the latter kind, I would like to remove "pages xx--yy" and replace it with something like "article no. z" in the rendering of my @inproceedings item.

Of course using `number` doesn't seem to work, as it is formatted as an issue number, pretty much in the same way as in a @article item.
That is confirmed by the `.blg` file:

> Warning--there's a number but no series in Bougeret2011

I use [the sig-alternate style](http://ipsn.acm.org/2010/IPSN_Submission%20instructions/sig-alternate.cls), hence we get:

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Casas2012,
    author = {Casas, Marc and de Supinski, Bronis and Bronevetsky, Greg and Schulz, Martin},
    title = {Fault Resilience of the Algebraic Multi-grid Solver},
    booktitle = {ICS},
    isbn = {978-1-4503-1316-2},
    doi = {10.1145/2304576.2304590},
    year = {2012},
    pages = {91--100},
}

@inproceedings{Bougeret2011,
    author = {Bougeret, Marin and Casanova, Henri and Rabie, Mikael and Robert, Yves and Vivien, Frédéric},
    title = {Checkpointing strategies for parallel jobs},
    booktitle = {SC},
    isbn = {978-1-4503-0771-0},
    doi = {10.1145/2063384.2063428},
    year = {2011},
    number = {1}, 
} % ^^^^^^ what should there be instead of 'number' here ?
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445888/best-practice-for-bibtex-entries-with-paper-number-rather-than-page-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up forking abbrv.bst to add `articleno` to the `ENTRY` list, and modify the `pages` function as follows:

```
FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages empty$
    { articleno empty$
        { "" }
        { "article no." articleno tie.or.space.connect }
      if$
    }
    { pages multi.page.check
        { "pages" pages n.dashify tie.or.space.connect }
        { "page" pages tie.or.space.connect }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Now I can use `articleno = {1}` in my .bib file.

Of course, when `format.pages` is conditionally called in the new .bst file, a `pages empty$` should probably be replaced by a `pages empty$ articleno empty$ and`, for items where it makes sense.