# How to cite articles using BibTeX for journal papers having an Article Number instead of Page Numbers?

Tags: bibtex, citing

I need help in citing research articles using BibTeX for journal papers having an Article Number instead of Pages Numbers? For instance, I ran BibTeX for a paper that appeared in MDPI Electronics journal. It compiled well, but when I see the PDF output, Article Number is not showing up in it. How to fix this problem? Your help is highly appreciated.

```
@Article{electronics10212707,
AUTHOR = {Djebbar, Fatiha},
TITLE = {Securing IoT Data Using Steganography: A Practical Implementation Approach},
JOURNAL = {Electronics},
VOLUME = {10},
YEAR = {2021},
NUMBER = {21},
ARTICLE-NUMBER = {2707}
}
```

Comment: I don't think I know any style that supports a field called `article-number` (I'm not even sure if a field name can contain `-`), certainly the base BibTeX and `natbib` styles don't know such a field, so it is no surprise that its contents don't show up. Unfortunately, the answer is: There is no unified approach that works for all styles. You have to experiment. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/445888/35864 (which is basically a duplicate). For some styles it might work to use the `pages` field, for others `note` might be an alternative.

Comment: Do please tell us which bibliography style you employ. It could be that the bib style you use is set to ignore the `number` field even if the `pages` field is empty.

Comment: Please note that the `number` field is for the number *of a journal or the volume/number of a book in a series* (see biblatex manual, page 24). Do not misuse it for the article number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my BibTeX entry & tested it with running LaTeX.

Now it works all right - I thank all for kind suggestions.

```
@Article{electronics10212707,
AUTHOR = {Djebbar, Fatiha},
TITLE = {Securing IoT Data Using Steganography: A Practical Implementation Approach},
JOURNAL = {Electronics},
VOLUME = {10},
YEAR = {2021},
NUMBER = {21},
NOTE = {{Article ID 2707}}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The preferable solution, if possible, is to use [biblatex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex). It supports article numbers with the `eid` field.

Alternatively...

a) if you use the ACM article master, you can use the field `articleno`

b) if you use the IEEEtran master, you can use the field `paper`

```
@Article{electronics10212707,
  author         = {Djebbar, Fatiha},
  journal        = {Electronics},
  title          = {Securing {IoT} Data Using Steganography: A Practical Implementation Approach},
  year           = {2021},
  number         = {21},
  volume         = {10},
  % Do not forget page numbers
  pages          = {1--17},
  % biblatex field
  eid            = {2707},
  % ACM field
  articleno      = {2707},
  % IEEE field
  paper          = {2707},
}
```

Note that the article still has page numbers, they just start at 1.

If you cannot use biblatex, or the publisher does not support the field, I often see two alternative approaches in practice:

1. Use the article number *instead* of the pages:

```
@Article{electronics10212707,
  % ...
  pages          = {2707},
}
```

2. *Prefix* the pages with the article number:

```
@Article{electronics10212707,
  % ...
  pages          = {2707:1--17},
}
```

I personally do not love either, but there you go.

p.s. Make sure to properly brace "IoT" in the title to prevent it from being lowercased.