# How to write the code for this article in bib?

Tags: bibliographies

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022053118303144?via%3Dihub

Its format is a little bit unusual: Journal of Economic Theory 199 (2022) 105075

Edit: Sorry for the confusion caused by my original post.
I am writing an article, and want to cite this paper. I am not submitting to this journal.

I say it is weird because usually the code for reference is written as

```
@article{blabla,
  title={Blabla},
  author={Blabla},
  journal={Blabla},
 volume={100},
  number={1},
  pages={1111-2222},
 year={2022}
}
```

But journal of economic theory has this "105075" and no range of pages. I was wondering how I should write the above code to make it shown as "Journal of Economic Theory 199 (2022) 105075"

Comment: Is this for a submission yourself, or just to match it? I've answered for the former case, might be worth clarifying in your question if the latter

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by the "format is a little bit unusual". Since the *JET* is an Elsevier-stable journal, I'd consider using the `elsarticle-harv` bibliography style to format the bibliographic entries.

Comment: Sorry my original post was confusing. I edited it to clarify my question.

Comment: I would set `volume=199`, `number=105075`, and `doi=https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jet.2020.105075` and omit the `pages` field. I trust you'll be able to figure out the `author`, `title`, `journal`, and `year` fields.

Comment: @Mico Then in the reference it is shown as "Journal of Economic Theory 199 (105075)". I am not sure whether it is right...

Comment: @Ypbor - What's shown and how it's formatted depends entirely on the bibliography style you employ. For instance, if you used the `elsarticle-harv` bibliography style, you'd get the `doi` field, but the `number` field would be omitted entirely.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/445888/35864. There is no consensus here across styles and so generally speaking you have to try a few things and see how the come out. With some styles `pages` will work well enough, with others it won't. Many `.bst` styles (certainly the standard styles after which most other styles are modelled to some degree) were written before online-only/non-print journals and their "article number" became a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "cite: export citation to Bibtex" has `pages = {105075}`, so I'd be tempted to go with that.

The full bibtex (without the abstract field) is:

```
@article{LEVY2022105075,
title = {Combining forecasts in the presence of ambiguity over correlation structures},
journal = {Journal of Economic Theory},
volume = {199},
pages = {105075},
year = {2022},
note = {Symposium Issue on Ambiguity, Robustness, and Model Uncertainty},
issn = {0022-0531},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jet.2020.105075},
url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022053118303144},
author = {Gilat Levy and Ronny Razin},
keywords = {Correlation neglect, Ambiguity, Point-wise mutual information}
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't rely on these automatically generated `.bib` files for the finder points of `.bib` file semantics. Many of these exported `.bib` files are not up to best practices (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/35864) and especially for more complex questions like this it is not clear that there even is a consensus across styles (the `.bib` file syntax is fixed and well known, the semantics can vary between styles even though a core set of fields and types is generally fairly stable).

Comment: Case in point: For most styles that I know `doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jet.2020.105075},` would not be best practice. Styles that support a dedicated DOI field generally assume that the field contains the bare DOI and not the link-y bit (`https://doi.org/`). So one would say `doi = {10.1016/j.jet.2020.105075},` instead.